# Как получить и изменить текущий уровень громкости для сигнала звонка Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-audio-record

В Android несколько ползунков звука.

```
1. Мультимедиа
2. Сигналы (звонки)
3. Будильник
4. Оповещения
```

Необходимо получить уровень громкости для сигнала звонка, а потом изменить его громкость на 0.

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод старый, но рабочий.

```
AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int value =  manager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Типы стримов я думаю найдете сами.

Так же советую ознакомиться с https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html Возможно для решения ваших задач он подойдет лучше

Answer (score 0):

Вот что помогло мне:

```
public class AudioControl {

    public static void setSoundValue(Context context, int value){
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, value, 0);
    }

    public static int getSoudValue(Context context){
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        return audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
    }

}
```